# How can i modify this string and get the value I want from JSON Object in java?

Tags: java, json

This is the response.

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "data": {
    "createdAt": "2019-12-09 15:21:07.0",
    "id": 3,
    "title": "{\"v\":\"1\"}",
    "token": "INACTIVE"
  },
  "message": "SUCCESS"
}
```

I need value of v which is 1. I'm getting this

```
{"v":"1"}
```

through

```
JSONObject r2 = new JSONObject(operation);
                String title = r2.getString("title");
                System.out.println(title);
```

How do I get the value of `v` after this?  It would be great if I could get any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `title` is a string with JSON text, so you need to re-invoke the JSON parser.

Also, in the question code, you forgot to navigate past the `data` node.

```
JSONObject rootObj = new JSONObject(operation); // parse JSON text
String title = rootObj.getJSONObject("data").getString("title"); // get "title" value
JSONObject titleObj = new JSONObject(title); // parse JSON text
String v = titleObj.getString("v"); // get "v" value
System.out.println(v); // prints: 1
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, got your logic.

Answer (score 1):

```java
String v= r2.getJSONObject("title").getString("v");
System.out.println(v);
```

PS: Don't forget to handle nulls,etc.

UPDATE: Please refer [Andreas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59246324/5221149) as it is the correct answer.  This answer wrongly assumes that `title` also contains json.

Comment: getString option does not even appear in suggestion. Not working.

Comment: The value of `title` is not a JSON object, but a string. The string content just happens to be another JSON text.

Comment: In the code snippet you have provided, you are calling calling `getString` on `r2` object which is of type `JSONObject` which is same as in the answer I have provided.

Comment: getting an error, saying title is not a json object

Comment: @SubhaBhowmik Because `title` is not a JSON object, and **this answer doesn't work**, for the reason I [already stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246071/how-can-i-modify-this-string-and-get-the-value-i-want-from-json-object-in-java/59246105#comment104702494_59246105). Don't know why it has been upvoted. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59246324/5221149) for working solution.

Comment: @Andreas I have updated my answer to reflect that the correct answer is the answer provided by you. Thank you